# XPath returning IndexError: list index out of range with Specific Example

Tags: xpath

In order to test lxml's XPath, I have created a test file called output1. This test file is a small, isolated snippet of XML. Running XPath on output1 works as expected. However, when I try to run my code on the full test file that output1 is extracted from, the code throws an error that does not make sense.

This is the file:

```
<ADMIN-DATA>
    <SOLAR>
        <PLANET GID="SOLAR-SYSTEM">
            <MOON GID="EDITABLE">
                  <EARTH GID="XPATH-EDITABLE">
                        <NUM GID="NAME">BongiornoPizza</NUM>
                  </EARTH>
            </MOON>
        </PLANET>
    </SOLAR>
</ADMIN-DATA>
```

My script begins parsing PLANET's children (starting with MOON, who has GID="EDITABLE"). The issue is that I can't use XPath to get the direct and only child of MOON, which is EARTH. However, I can iterate using a for loop and manually get to EARTH. This is strange, considering I also tested it on an even smaller example using XPath and it worked.

The for loop `for inner_node in node:` works fine, and will get me EARTH.

Breaking code: (Using XPath to get EARTH)

```py
if "function Comment" not in str(node.tag):
    if node.attrib["GID"] == "EDITABLE": # passes
        xpath_editable_node = node.xpath('./EARTH')[0] # BREAKS ON THIS LINE
        name_node = xpath_editable_node.xpath('./NUM')[0]
        print(name_node.text) # should contain BongiornoPizza
```

Working code: (Uses for loop to get EARTH)

```py
if "function Comment" not in str(node.tag):
    if node.attrib["GID"] == "EDITABLE": # passes
        for inner_node in node:
            print(inner_node)
            if inner_node.attrib["GID"] == "XPATH-EDITABLE":
                print("INSIDE")
                name_node = inner_node.xpath('./NUM')[0]
                print(name_node.text) # should contain BongiornoPizza
```

I can achieve what I want with for loops and manual iteration, but it would be nice to be able to consistently use the XPath library in a clean manner. I think I'm probably missing a simple thing and that's why it is not working.

Comment: Could be due to empty elements so `node.xpath('./EARTH')` returns an empty node set

Comment: @LMC Empty elements as in no children in the element? In that case, that shouldn't be possible since there is children (so it's not empty).

Comment: Your "Breaking code" works fine for me (no "index out of range"). I suggest you provide complete code we can run.

Comment: Empty element as `<MOON GID="EDITABLE" />` that would throw the described error at `node.xpath('./EARTH')[0]`